# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli as array

Tags: ubuntu, mysqli, apache2, php-7

I don't understand why this line:

```
$this->db = mysqli($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pass'],$db['name']);
```

Give me that error:

> [05-Jul-2017 11:55:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
>   Cannot use object of type mysqli as array in
>   /var/www/***/public_html/core/classes.php:7
>
> Stack trace: #0 /var/www/***/public_html/core/classes.php(19):
>   Database->connectDatabase()
>
> 1 /var/www/***/public_html/index.php(5): Core->__construct()
>
> 2 {main} thrown in /var/www/***/public_html/core/classes.php on line 7

I'm running Ubuntu Apache PHP7, phpinfo() does mention the mysqli ext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried with keyword **new** before mysqli

```
$this->db = new mysqli($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pass'],$db['name']);
```

Also check, is any of given parameters to mysqli function is array (it may cause the error).
`$db['host'],$db['pass'],$db['user'],$db['name']` should be strings

Comment: Could you `print_r($db)` and post the output here, and remove the informations that you don't want to show here.

Comment: I've printed $db then realized my config file stored credential in $_db['host'] = "127.0.0.1" ... and the mysqli() was $db, changed it now it works.

Comment: Nice to know it! Best regards!